# use runtime type (in c#) for logic flow

Tags: c#, .net, oop

This question is similar to (a subset of) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447947/is-type-checking-ever-ok)

In this case it is using runtime type to distinguish between a success and a failure returned results.

Quite often I see following pattern:

```
public struct Result {
    public boolean IsSuccess { get;set;}
    public string ErrorMessage {get;set;}
    public int Value {get;set;}
}
...
Result result = someObject.SomeMethod();
if (result.IsSuccess) DoSomething(result.Value);
else handleError(result.ErrorMessage);
```

I think that following is more natural, and expresses the intention more clear (in my opinion):

```
public abstract class Result { }
public sealed class Failure : Result {
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
public sealed class Success : Result {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
...
Result result = someObject.SomeMethod();
if (result is Success) DoSomething((result as Success).Value);
else if (result is Failure) handleError((result as Failure).ErrorMessage);
```

Also note that .Net (and many other languages) use this pattern in try-catch block with multiple catch clauses (where exception type selects a catch block).

**EDIT:** this pattern (i.e. relying on runtime type) is identical to discriminated unions of F#, the difference is that in F# it is native, and in C# it is emulated using constructs meant for different purposes.

**EDIT:** I think my main issue with first code is a code smell "partially initialized object". In 100% of cases only half of the object will be initialized. It also *almost* violates ISP, "almost" because once .IsSuccess is evaluated only part of the object will be used henceforth (if it is success only .Result is used, if it is an error - only error properties are used). Run-type checking solution does not have those issues.

**So the question is:** what are the issues with using this pattern? I am especially interested in issues from following perspectives: maintainability, readability, testability, conceptual purity, and OOP/OOD.

Comment: If you care about intent then never use an "as" cast for something you're certain of. If result is success then ((Success)result).Value

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule I prefer the first form.

The second example takes more keystrokes and adds 4 type checking operations. It's also less obvious to the consumer (you can't confuse the meaning of an `IsSuccess` property). It seems less logical to have to perform a type conversion just to ascertain the result of an operation (seems similar to using exceptions for program flow; you *can* do it but you shouldn't).

In addition, the first form can serve as a platform-independent mechanism for describing the data. The second cannot. In other words, you could easily serialize a result type comprised of primitives and share it with any consumer but requiring type-checking limits/eliminates that possibility.

To improve the quality of your `Result` object, you could make a `Messages` collection  which contains more than just a string (perhaps include code, severity, message, etc.). This allows all of your results to return messages, not just operations which fail. If an operation fails, you can probably assume that `Messages` contains at least one error message (and/or query the collection using LINQ to find all error-related messages).

Comment: In addition the latter is lot heavier if we're doing premature optimization. While the struct will have to store its string on the heap that class based version will store everything on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

The somewhat academical reason for second form being wrong goes something like:

C#, as an OO language, designed with an assumption that *classes* will be used to model *categories* of the underlying system (business concepts, for example), while *instances* will be used to model facts.

Using *classes* to model facts is a misuse of the tool.

Though I still don't know what the practical ramifications would be.

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented design is not important on throw-away information. This result object has a very limited lifespan and therefore belongs as a struct on the stack.

If you want to talk maintenance/readability then people will be initially confused by this code.

If you want to go object-oriented on error dissemination then purely use exceptions (although that will degrade the performance of these use-cases a touch).